# How to programatically add new children to a deeply nested object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Consider the following object, which is composed by an unknown number of deeply nested children.

```
 const state = {
  id: 1,
  children: [
    {
      id: 3,
      children: [
        {
          id: 4,
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      children: []
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I programatically push a new object to the `children` array of a node knowing only its `id` and the array of `id`s of its parents?
I thought using recursion but I couldn't find a solution that worked. I am also using immutability-helper, so I have tried using `Array.reduce()` to return an object that looked like this:

```
    const newState = {
      children: {
        [idxOfNodeToChange]: {
          children: {$push: newChildren}
        }
      }
    }
```

so I could pass it to `update()` but there I am even more stuck since I would still have to traverse through the accumulator every time to go as deep as needed, and I'm not sure how to do that. Any ideas?

Extra info: I'm using a D3 library for React called VX and this structure is required to build a tree component, so I'm stuck on how to add new nodes programatically.

Comment: Recursively find the object by the id.  Once you find it, manipulate it's children.

Comment: If you are having an issue with your attempt at recursion, provide that logic so we can help you debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. You can use this recursive function to search by id and append data to the found node's children array.

```
function appendChildToNode(node, nodeId, data) {
  // If the node is empty, just return it as is.
  if (!node) {
    return node;
  }

  let children;

  if (node.id === nodeId) {
    // If the node has the id we're searching for, 
    // append the data to its children.
    children = [...node.children, data];
  } else {
    // Otherwise, apply the function recursively to each of its children 
    children = node.children.map(childNode => appendChildToNode(childNode, nodeId, data));
  }  

  return { ...node, children };
}
```

It is immutable and you may use it like this:

```
const newState1 = appendChildToNode(state, 4, { id: 5, children: [] });
const newState2 = appendChildToNode(state, 2, { id: 5, children: [] });
```

**See it working in the example snippet below.**

```js
const state = {
  id: 1,
  children: [{
      id: 3,
      children: [{
        id: 4,
        children: []
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      children: []
    }
  ]
};

const newState1 = appendChildToNode(state, 4, {
  id: 5,
  children: []
});
const newState2 = appendChildToNode(state, 2, {
  id: 5,
  children: []
});

console.log(state); // Orginal state should not be mutated.
console.log(newState1);
console.log(newState2);

function appendChildToNode(node, nodeId, data) {
  // If the node is empty, just return it as is.
  if (!node) {
    return node;
  }

  let children;

  if (node.id === nodeId) {
    // If the node has the id we're searching for, 
    // append the data to its children.
    children = [...node.children, data];
  } else {
    // Otherwise, apply the function recursively to each of its children 
    children = node.children.map(childNode => appendChildToNode(childNode, nodeId, data));
  }

  return { ...node, children };
}
```

---

**Update:** The above function uses [ES6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to append items. If you need to support older browsers w/o transpilation, you can use this updated version using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
function appendChildToNode(node, nodeId, data) {
  if (!node) {
    return node;
  }

  var children;
  
  if (node.id === nodeId) {
    children = node.children.concat([data]);
  } else {
    children = node.children.map(childNode => appendChildToNode(childNode, nodeId, data));
  }
  
  return Object.assign({}, node, { children });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's find the node with ID 3 in our state, searching one level deep. Take the *children* of the **current node**, and *find the node with correct ID* within those children:

```
id = 3
node3 = state.children.find(v => v == id)
```

In that node, find ID 4. Now we're searching in the children of **node 3**:

```
id = 4 // ┌ act on node3!
node4 = node3.children.find(v => v == id)
```

Fitting that to [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), the *accumulator* is **the current node**. It starts at the root node `state`, and then traverses the tree downwards: each time, we traverse the tree one level, using the next ID from a list of IDs. We need the recursion to start at the root of the tree, so the initial value is `state`, our root node.

If we take the above examples and `reduce` them:

```
[3, 4].reduce((acc, x) => acc.children.find(v => v === x), state)
// ids                    traverse one level               start at root node
```

Unrolling it, this is equivalent to:

```
(state.children.find(v => v === 3)).children.find(v => v === 4)
```

The general form becomes:

```
const recursiveTraversal = ids => 
  ids.reduce((acc, x) => acc.children.find(v => v === x), state)
```